# Is it possible for human beings to feed through the nose?

Tags: human-physiology, nose

There is a prediction on a futurology site that food can be eaten by inhalation

https://2050.earth/predictions/smell-can-feed-you

[Although aerosol foods do exist](https://www.spraytm.com/aerosol-foods-shorten-prep-time-for-a-variety-of-categories.html) they are still eaten by the mouth.

Is there any biological evidence that human beings can feed through their noses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to SE Worldbuilding.

Comment: @David I've come to Worldbuilding to say that this is not a worldbuilding question, as it deals with real human biology, and not fiction.

Comment: @AndyD273 — You could have fooled me!

Comment: Do you actually mean inhalation, ie that you'd absorb nutrients through your lungs? Because otherwise, the nose is connected to the stomach via the esophagus and you can be fed through that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasogastric_intubation

Answer (score 1):

Certain vitamins, for example, [vitamin B12](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1873990/), can be absorbed through the nasal mucosa by simple diffusion.

Many nutrients can be absorbed through the intestinal mucosa only by the help of specific carriers. These carriers are not likely present in nasal mucosa, so the nutrients in question may not be absorbed there.

The other problem, especially with macronutrients (carbs, proteins, fats), is if the surface area of nasal mucosa is big enough to absorb large amounts of macronutrients (carbs, proteins, fats) needed to meet nutritional demands. In one experiment, only 0.1 mg of [glucose](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/691147) from a given dose was absorbed through the *oral* mucosa.

In another experiment, some [amino acids](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00806002) were absorbed from *oral* mucosa.